# How to hide only the Close (x) button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a modal dialog, and need to hide the Close (X) button, but I cannot use 
`ControlBox = false`, because I need to keep the Minimize and Maximize buttons.

I need to hide just Close button, is there any way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Update: I had permission to disable it, which is simpler :) Thanks all!

Comment: Could this be what yuo want: [Hide Close Button [X] of Win Forms in C#.NET](http://sameeramrutia.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hide-close-button-x-of-win-forms-in-cnet/) just googled: `hide close button c#`, second result here! =)

Comment: you are wrong, i do not want disable button, but HIDE it.. are u able to find a solution ?

Comment: Need is a strong word.  Where is this requirement coming from?  What is the actual requirement - that the user can't terminate the program, or that the UI "looks like it doesn't have a close button"?  Because there are other ways around this, and you're going to be hard pressed to completely close off all of them (e.g. task manager, taskkill, possibly alt+f4, etc).  I personally wouldn't work too hard at this, because unless you're re-skinning your whole app anyhow, it will be wasted effort, and break user expectations/continuity with other Windows programs.

Comment: @Sayem it reveals this page, so don't be such a critic.

Comment: Scratch the minimize button off your list as well.  Minimizing a modal dialog will automatically make it close.  Necessarily so, it is the only window left that's still enabled.  When you minimize it, there would not be any window left that can still get the focus so the user can't get back to your program.  You are now in "does this still make sense?" territory.  It doesn't.

Comment: I'm late to the party but I have the hunch that this requirement comes from a wish to force the user to leave the dialog exclusively in ways which are under control of the user code, most likely form buttons; perhaps one wants to force the user to make an explicit choice. Is "no cancel option"  indeed a valid requirement? Can the user not legitimately choose to undo whatever click made the dialog appear? If he can't, or shouldn't: Could simply closing the dialog be interpreted as "no"?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can't hide it, but you can disable it by overriding the CreateParams property of the form.

```
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
       CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
       myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON ;
       return myCp;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DisableClose.aspx

Comment: thanks, i found this solution, but we would like hide it, not just disable :( anywat thanks!

Comment: there isn't a way other than to design your form from scratch.

Comment: yeah. better make your own form with your own controlbox without the close button then hide the parent form's control box.

Comment: Answer from 'Abhishek.Chopra' is simple and effective.

Comment: How to enable it during runtime again?

Comment: To anyone else who finds this answer, *does* want to just disable rather than completely hide it, I am leaving this comment to clarify that, yes, despite the name "NOCLOSE_BUTTON", which you would *think* would make it so there was, well, no close button, it is actually just disabling it. Which is what I wanted, in this case.

Answer (score 186):

We can hide close button on form by setting `this.ControlBox=false;`

Note that this hides all of those sizing buttons. Not just the X. In some cases that may be fine.

Comment: Did you read the question where he specified that that wasn't an option?

Comment: Did a Google search and this SO QA was the top hit.  And this answer was what I was looking for.  Thank you Abhishek...

Comment: If you want ONLY the `X` to show, in the Form Designer under the "Windows Style" section for the form, set the following: (1) ControlBox = True, (2) MaximizeBox = False, (3) MinimizeBox = False.

Answer (score 30):

Well, you can hide it, by removing the entire system menu:

```
private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style &= ~WS_SYSMENU;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Of course, doing so removes the minimize and maximize buttons.

If you keep the system menu but remove the close item then the close button remains but is disabled.

The final alternative is to paint the non-client area yourself. That's pretty hard to get right.

Comment: This works too, great! But *ControlBox = false* is easy to use as your way.

Comment: This is the same as setting `ControlBox` to false.  Also, it fails the requirement: _I need to keep the Minimize and Maximize buttons_

Answer (score 9):

If you really want to hide it, as in "not visible", then you will probably have to create a borderless form and draw the caption components yourself.  VisualStyles library has the Windows Elements available.  You would also have to add back in the functionality of re-sizing the form or moving the form by grabbing the caption bar.  Not to mention the system menu in the corner.

In most cases, it's hard to justify having the "close" button not available, especially when you want a modal form with minimizing capabilities.  Minimizing a modal form really makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can hide the close button by changing the FormBorderStyle from the properties section or programmatically in the constructor using:

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
}
```

then you create a menu strip item to exit the application.

cheers