# Modal dialog appear

Tags: c#, winforms

In my GUI I want that when I click a button a modal dialog appear in-front of my GUI with the `msg "busy"`. How can I do it?

Moreover, modal dialog should not have options of closing it (no cross button in top right corner). I want to close it programatically after 2-3 seconds of pressing button

PS: This is what I have so far

```
Form frm1 = new Form();
frm1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
frm1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
frm1.ControlBox = false;
frm1.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Yes, you want, that's nice. Can't see a hint of what have you tried so far.

Comment: In winforms you can't hide a close button - look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301825/windows-forms-how-to-hide-close-x-button) or without border like proposed Aniket.

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: @Ritro, you can hide a close button, exactly as Aniket says; set the <form>.ControlBox = false. Granted, you lose the min and max buttons as well, but oh well.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue, I think it even be better without the whole border and all buttons since it's like loading splash screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want the title bar on top then use the code below (do remember to look into MSDN for more info on each of these)

```
Form f = new Form();
f.FormBorderStyle=FormBorderStyle.None; //no border frame, close button etc gone!
f.ShowDialog(); // Modal dialog
```

If you only want to hide all the buttons above on the top-right corner:

```
f.ControlBox = false;
```