# C# Controlbox disable

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable **Only** the close button of my windows form

```
this.ControlBox = false;
```

disables all the function even the minimize and maximize button

is there other way to solve this.
It is OK if it is visible but cannot be clicked.

Comment: Please refer to this link: [Windows Forms: How to hide Close (x) button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301825/windows-forms-how-to-hide-close-x-button)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable only the "X" button from controlbox. You can change the FormBorderStyle and build your own custom buttons.

If you want it to be visible but change the close behavior, you can listen `Form_Closing` event and check the CloseReason property of `FormClosingEventArgs` object.