# C# form: how to disable upper right close button, but keep minimize?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a C# forms app with 3 forms:  main window, sub window 1, and sub window 2.

I want only main window to have close button (the standard X in upper right corner of window).

The sub windows should have only minimize button and no max and no close button (X).

I disabled maximmizeBox, enabled minimizeBox, but how can I hide or disable the close X in the upper right corner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301825/windows-forms-how-to-hide-close-x-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Forms: How to hide Close (x) button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301825/windows-forms-how-to-hide-close-x-button)